# Орфография

Tags: орфография

Не могу убедить своего упрямого оппонента, что в его фразе: "Убеждён, что теперь Вы будете более осмотрительнее относится к ..." содержатся две ошибки: 1)либо слово более - лишнее "на этом празднике жизни", либо в слове осмотрительнее надо поменять окончание ЕЕ на О, 2)в слове относится пропущен мягкий знак. - Помогите.
P.S. Первая ошибка напомнила Свету из Иванова с ее нетленкой: "более лучше одеваться".

Answer (score 5):

Вы абсолютно правы.
Следует сказать либо "более осмотрительно", либо просто "осмотрительнее". Посоветуйте Вашему оппоненту обратиться к учебнику Д.Э. Розенталя "Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке".
Что касается пропущенного мягкого знака, то для проверки следует задать вопрос: вы будете что делать? - относиться. В вопросе мягкий знак, значит, и в глаголе пишем мягкий знак.

Comment: Спасибо, Татьяна!
Я ему талдычу: "Что делает? - Относится. Что делать? - Относиться". А он мне в ответ" "Относиться - всего лишь один из правильных вариантов". Вот и приходится обращаться за авторитетной помощью.
Спасибо.